# Set slider to initial position - React native

Tags: react-native, slider

I have an app in which there is a common slider to display 2 different data values. And a `button` which controls the values to show (i.e. To use `Array1 Or Array2`). 
`Slider` is displaying all values properly while doing back-n-forth in `slider`.

When I click the `button`, I update the `state`, `Render` gets called with correct `Array` to load from.

Issue: `Slider` starts from some random position. I want slider head to go to initial position.

Below is my slider code,

```
 <Slider style={styleSliderView.slider}
                minimumValue={0}
                maximumValue={arr.length-1}
                step={1}
                onValueChange={(value)=>this._onValueChange(value)}/>
```

Any thoughts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably not just a random position. It's the new position at the new min/max range. What you need to do is somehow reset the slider.

You can try 2 possible solutions:

1) save the slider value in your state and reset it when the button is pressed:

```
<Slider
  value={this.state.value}
  onValueChange={(value) => this.setState({value})}
/>

onButtonPress() {
  this.setState({value: 0});
}
```

2) reset the value using a ref to the slider:

```
<Slider
  ref={r => this.slider = r}
/>

onButtonPress() {
  this.slider.setNativeProps({value: 0});
}
```

Comment: Possible to have animations here?

Comment: @BhumitMehta while iOS will let you set a slider value animated, as far as I know RN doesn't expose a way to do it

Comment: The first example won't work, because `<Slider>` is an uncontrolled component. The second example works well.